# undefined variable in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

in this my code `data` is undefined why?
i can't access to data.message.

```
$.post("actions.php", {name_madan: madan , postaction:'sabte_madan' },
    function(data){
    if (data.success)
           alert(data.message);
    });
```

actions.php

```
case 'sabte_madan':
    $query="SELECT * from maadan WHERE name_madan='{$_POST['name_madan']}'";
    $result=$db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery($query));
    if ( !$result )
    {           
    $data['success']=true;  $data['message']='ok';
    }
    else $data['success']=false;    $data['message']='no';              

break;

if ( isset ($data)) echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Looks like `$data` is only being set if `!$result`. Are you missing the `else` part of the `if` statement?

Comment: You need to add `,'json'` to your `$.post` to tell jQuery to parse it as JSON.

Comment: May be this can help 
`if ( !$result )
    {           
    $data['success']=false; 
    $data['message']='ok';
    }
else
{
$data['success']=true;
}`

Comment: Anyway, can you insert some debugging into this `case` block?

Comment: Also, I wonder how exactly do you check for `data` undefinedness. Or it's `data.success` that is not `true` here? Also, do you understand that your code is vulnerable to SQL injections?

Answer (score 1):

you miss 'json' data type

```
$.post("actions.php", {name_madan: madan , postaction:'sabte_madan' },
    function(data){
        if (data.success)
           alert(data.message);
    },'json');
```